# Transitioning shapes in CSS not working

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to run some simple css experiments for transitioning shapes created with css.

I can do it with jQuery just fine, but I am trying to keep things as light weight as possible for the the actual project I have in mind. I've been using Google quite a bit (and W3schools) to brush up on all of this, but I am starting to wonder if everyone is just using jQuery these days.

Anyway. I want to expand a circle to look more like capsule. The code is below.

http://pastebin.com/piXXrmEu

Not sure what I am missing. Just need the circle to gain a width of 700px. It's not currently working in any browser. Though it needs to work in all IE browsers.

Comment: Add a [mcve] to your question please.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on what event you want the circle to expand, but here is an example of a circle expanding to a 'capsule' shape onHover just using CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/1cdatxq2/

```
#circle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: orange;
    -moz-border-radius: 300px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 300px;
    border-radius: 300px;
    transition: width .5s;
}

#circle:hover{
    width: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More flexible will be variant with animation, i think

```
#circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 300px;
  animation: run 2s
}

@keyframes run {
  0% {
    width: 200px
  }
  25% {
    width: 300px
  }
  50% {
    width: 400px
  }
  75% {
    width: 500px
  }
}
```

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dimitrioglo/asvxm4dk/)